# What is the function/meaning of this "こと"

Tags: grammar

> (1)A (2)B を表すように、二分したものがそれぞれ別々の意味になれば**こと**は簡単であるが、言葉の場合は、なかなか...

Usually こと functions as a "形式名詞" or other grammatical roles, but this one seems not a "形式名詞" since the former part of the sentence is "ば"(仮定表現). How should I interpret this "こと" in "**こと**は簡単である"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

「こと」 roughly means "***the matter***" in that context.  As you stated, it is not used as a dummy noun there.

> "If each of the bisected parts had a different meaning as in "(1)A (2)B", the matter would be simple, but as for words/language, it would not be very (simple)."